# Fastapi service deployed on AWS keeps restarting every 10 minutes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, fastapi, openai-api

I have a fastapi service deployed on AWS, the API sends request to OpenAI API to generate text.

This API had been running fine for 2-3 days but now it keeps restarting on it's own after every 10 minutes. There are no errors or any helpful information in the AWS logs.

I also set request_timeout to 30 seconds in case this was happening because OpenAI API took too long to respond.

Any info about this is appreciated.

edit:
start.sh file contains this line: `python3 main.py`

and main.py is as follows:

```
import uvicorn

if __name__ ="__main__":
   uvicorn.run("app.main:app, host="0.0.0.0", port=9026, reload=True)
```

**Note**: When the service is not being used the container does not restart, it only happens when requests are being made to the service that the container restarts every 10-20 minutes depending on the number of requests.

Comment: @AllanChua I have shared it

Comment: could you also share what are you using to host this API?

Comment: @AllanChua AWS ECS

Comment: Does your container have any health check API? If yes, did you integrated it with the ECS service? How was the ECS cluster provisioned?

Comment: I think health check is missing

Comment: @app.get("/health") endpoint would do?

Answer (score 0):

you need to try `uvicorn app.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9026`
in bash script to run, It is just another way to run.

Comment: how will this help... just curious about what is wrong with the other way

Answer (score 0):

Please check health check in Task Definition

Its mentioned here:
[uvicorn shutting down after 1-2 minutes on AWS Fargate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73818557/uvicorn-shutting-down-after-1-2-minutes-on-aws-fargate)